Redraw a Recurrent Neural Network
I need some help to redraw the RNN from this answer:
I have modified the code a bit, and this is what i have so far (just for the right side of the = sign):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz} % Para fazer desenhos
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
% \usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,calc, shapes,positioning,shadows,arrows.meta,calligraphy}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[item/.style={circle,draw,thick,align=center},itemc/.style={item,on chain,join}]
        \begin{scope}[start chain=going right,nodes=itemc,every join/.style={-latex,very thick},local bounding box=chain]
            \path node (A0) {$\Sigma|\Theta$} node (A1) {$\Sigma|\Theta$} node (A2) {$\Sigma|\Theta$} node[xshift=2em] (AT){$\Sigma|\Theta$};
        \end{scope}
         \foreach \X in {0,1,2,T} {
            \draw[very thick,-latex] (A\X.north) -- ++ (0,2em) node[above,item,fill=purple!50] (h\X) {$h_\X$};
            \draw[very thick,latex-] (A\X.south) -- ++ (0,-2em) node[below,item,fill=green!50] (x\X) {$x_\X$};
        }
        \path (x2) -- (xT) node[midway,scale=2,font=\bfseries] {\dots};
        \draw[very thick, -latex] ([yshift=-1em]x0.south) -- node[below] {Tempo} ([yshift=-1em]xT.south);
        \path (x0.west) ++ (-1em,0) node (zero) {$0$};
        \draw[very thick,-latex] (zero) -- (A0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

The result:

But, i would like this instead:

So, no more arrows leaving the A0, A1, A2 nodes. Instead of that, arrows should start from the north arrow and end at south of next AX node.

Search in the pgfmanual: a) -| and |-, b)look up polar notation for nodes. I.e. if the node is named (a), then (a.0) is at the east side of the shape, (a.90) is north, and (a.250) is roughly the entry point you want. // Please add the missing lines to make your code compile. Thank you

@MS-SPO Missing lines added, thanks for the information.

Fine. Please feel free to answer your own question, once you found a solution. This will help future user. Thank you

Something like this:
Edit:
Added picture elements which I forgot to draw in original MWE. Now result of it is more similar to desired result.

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package
                positioning,
                }
\makeatletter
\tikzset{suspend join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2em and 4em,
  start chain = going above,
   arr/.style = {thick, {Stealth[scale=0.8]}-},
     V/.style = {circle, draw, thick, fill=#1, 
                 minimum size=2em, inner sep = 2pt,
                 on chain, join=by -Stealth, thick
                 }
                       ]
\node  (A0) [V=green!30]    {$x_{0}$}; 
\node  (B0) [V=white]      {$\Sigma|\Theta$}; 
\node  (C0) [V=purple!30]  {$h_{0}$};
     \foreach \i [count=\j from 0, count=\k] in {1,2,T}
{
    \ifnum\j=2
\node  (A\k) [V=green!30, suspend join,
              right=7em of A\j] {$x_{\i}$}; 
    \else
\node  (A\k) [V=green!30, suspend join,
              right=of A\j] {$x_{\i}$}; 
    \fi
\node  (B\k) [V=white]      {$\Sigma|\Theta$}; 
\node  (C\k) [V=purple!30]  {$h_{\i}$};
}

     \foreach \i [count=\j] in {0,1}
\draw[arr] 
        (B\j.240) -- ++ (0,-1.5em) -|- ($(B\i)!0.5!(C\i)$);

\draw[arr]  (B0) -- ([xshift=-1.5em] A0.north west) 
                node[anchor=north east, inner xsep=0pt] {0};
\draw[arr, densely dashed] 
        (B3.240) -- ++ (0,-1.5em) -|- ($(B2)!0.45!(C2)$);
\path   (A2) -- node[font=\Huge] {\dots}   (A3);
\draw [arr] ([yshift=-1em]A3.south) -- node[below] {Tempo} ([yshift=-1em]A0.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


I have just added the options count=\i and remember=\X as \lastX (see "Options to customize the foreach-statement", source) in the foreach loop provided by tikz. You can modify the value -110 in (A\X.-110) to adjust the ending point of the arrow dynamically. I've also changed the every join style to remove the horizontal connections between each cell.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz} % Para fazer desenhos
\usetikzlibrary{chains, calc}
% \usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows,calc, shapes,positioning,shadows,arrows.meta,calligraphy}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        item/.style={
            circle,
            draw,
            thick,
            align=center
        },
        itemc/.style={
            item,
            on chain,
            join
        }
    ]
        \begin{scope}[
            start chain=going right,
            nodes=itemc,
            every join/.style={
                %-latex,
                %very thick
                draw=none
            },
            local bounding box=chain
        ]
            \path node (A0) {$\Sigma|\Theta$} node (A1) {$\Sigma|\Theta$} node (A2) {$\Sigma|\Theta$} node [xshift=2em] (AT) {$\Sigma|\Theta$};
        \end{scope}
        
        \foreach \X [count=\i, remember=\X as \lastX] in {0,1,2,T} {
            \draw [very thick, -latex] (A\X.north) -- ++ (0,2em) node[above, item, fill=purple!50] (h\X) {$h_\X$};
            \draw [very thick, latex-] (A\X.south) -- ++ (0,-2em) node[below, item, fill=green!50] (x\X) {$x_\X$};
            
            \ifnum\i>1
                \draw [-latex, ultra thick, red] ($(h\lastX.south)!0.5!(A\lastX.north)$) -| ($(A\lastX)!0.5!(A\X)$) |- ([xshift=-2mm, yshift=-4mm]A\X.south) -| (A\X.-110);
            \fi
        }
        
        
        \path (x2) -- (xT) node[midway,scale=2,font=\bfseries] {\dots};
        \draw [very thick, -latex] ([yshift=-1em]x0.south) -- node[below] {Tempo} ([yshift=-1em]xT.south);
        \path (x0.west) ++ (-1em,0) node (zero) {$0$};
        \draw [very thick,-latex] (zero) -- (A0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


